# Rabbi Moshe Feinstein member of Sanhedrin

Tags: maseches-sanhedrin, moshe-feinstein, sanhedrin

On page 198 of "Reb Moshe" published by Artscroll, it is told of Reb Moshe that he "needed a cardiac pacemaker inserted in his chest....Reb Moshe said, 'I know that I am not worthy to be a member of the Sanhedrin, but in this generation, I may be one of those selected when Mashiach comes.  I fear that the surgery will make me a ba'al mum, thus disqualifying me.'"  However, even without the pacemaker, how could Reb Moshe be appointed to the sanhedrin, when the Talmud rules in Sanhedrin 17a that "one may appoint to a sanhedrin only men of height, men of wisdom, men of appearance, men of old age, men acquainted with witchcraft," and Reb Moshe was by all accounts well under five feet tall and thus not a "man of height"?

Answer (score 13):

This law is codified by Rambam in [Hilchot Sanhedrin 2:6](https://hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?rid=14235):

> כשם שבית דין מנוקין בצדק כך צריכין להיות מנוקין מכל מומי הגוף וצריך להשתדל ולבדוק ולחפש שיהיו כולן בעלי שיבה בעלי קומה בעלי מראה נבוני לחש ושידעו ברוב הלשונות כדי שלא תהא סנהדרין שומעת מפי התורגמן
>
> Just as the judges of a court must be on the highest level of righteousness; so, too, must they be unsullied by any physical blemishes.
>
> An effort should be made that they all be white-haired, of impressive height, of dignified appearance, men who understand whispered matters, who understand many different languages so that the Sanhedrin will not need to hear testimony from an interpreter.
>
> ([Touger translation](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/1172725/jewish/Sanhedrin-vehaOnashin-haMesurin-lahem-Chapter-2.htm))

The language used here implies that it is ideal to have these qualities, but not absolutely necessary. Indeed, several commentators there say this explicitly. The Kessef Mishneh writes:

> ספ"ק דסנהדרין ופרק ששי דמנחות אמר רבי יוחנן אין מושיבין בסנהדרין אלא בעלי קומה ובעלי חכמה ובעלי מראה ובעלי זקנה ובעלי כשפים ויודעים בשבעים לשון שלא תהא סנהדרין שומעת מפי התורגמן וכתב רבינו יודעין ברוב הלשונות משום דדבר זר הוא להמציא מי שידע בכל שבעים לשון ומשמע לרבינו דהאי אין מושיבין היינו דהיכא דמשתכחי אבל אי לא משתכחי לא מעכבי כל הני ויש סעד לדבר מדאמרו גבי משה ואילו נבוני לא אשכח

The Lechem Mishneh writes:

> משמע דהנהו לא הוו לעיכובא אלא לכתחלה צריך לבדוק אחר אלו. וקשה דבסוף פ"ק דסנהדרין אמר ר' יוחנן אין מושיבין בסנהדרין אלא בעלי קומה ובעלי חכמה ובעלי מראה ובעלי זקנה ובעלי כשפים ויודעים בשבעים לשון ע"כ וכיון דר' יוחנן כייל להני דכתב כאן רבינו בעלי חכמה ובעלי כשפים מנין לו לרבינו לחלק ולומר דדוקא הנהו תרי דבעלי חכמה בעלי כשפים הוו לעיכובא כמ"ש לעיל אין מעמידין בסנהדרין וכו' אבל כל הני לא הוו לעיכובא אלא לכתחילה דווקא צריך לבדוק אחר אלה ואפשר לומר דהכריחו לומר כן מדאיצטריך קרא דומום אין בך למעוטי מומי הגוף כמו שמבואר בדברי רב יוסף שהזכרתי משמע דבהיותם נקיים ממום אע"ג דלא יהיו יפים סגי וכל אלה התנאים של בעלי מראה ובעלי שיבה ובעלי קומה תנאים של יופי הם ומסתייה דמיעט לן קרא בעלי מומים אלא שנאמר שאם אינם יפים לא סגי בלאו הכי זו אין סברא אלא ודאי שלא אמרן ר' יוחנן אלא על צד היותר טוב ולא לעיכובא וזה דקדק רבינו כשסמך הדין הנזכר פה עם שלפניו כשם שב"ד מנוקין וכו' אבל אין תירוץ זה מספיק למ"ש ויודעים בשבעים לשון דאינו לעכובא אלא לכתחלה דמאין לו כן ונראה לומר דהסברא ודאי הכריחו לרבינו לומר כן דודאי בעלי חכמה ובעלי כשפים שהוא הדבר התלוי בחכמה זה נאמר לעכובא אבל כל הני דאינם תלויים בחכמה לא נאמרו אלא לכתחלה וצ"ע